# Why are my generic array elements null? (trying to copy elements into new array)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, copy

I have a symbol table class which uses two generic and comparable arrays, Keys[] and Value[]. In main(), I read from input(a text file), and fill the symbol table arrays accordingly. I am trying to create a method, wherein I want to copy  Value[] vals into a new array. However, my vals[] elements which make up the symbol table together with Keys[] keys, print null. Why am I getting null, and more importantly, what is a general way to fix this issue?

Since the symbol table has been instantiated, and the arrays have been subsequently filled by put(), I expected vals[z] to contain some integer values which could be used to copy into another array, yet the whole array is null? Some code below is omitted, shown are the main functions put(), get() and rank()

```
public class SymbolTable<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value extends Comparable<Value>> {
    private Key[] keys;
    private Value[] vals;
    private int N = 0;

    // problem here when trying to copy generic arrays
    public void function(int x, int y){
        // Copy vals into valscopy
        Value[] valscopy;
        valscopy = (Value[]) new Comparable[vals.length];
        for(int z = 0; z < valscopy.length; z++){
            valscopy[z] = vals[z]; 
        }


        for(int i = valscopy.length-1; i >= valscopy.length-((y-x)+1); i--){
            StdOut.println(valscopy[i] + " " + vals[i]); <------ both print null
        }
    }



    public SymbolTable(int capacity)
    {
        keys = (Key[]) new Comparable[capacity];
        vals = (Value[]) new Comparable[capacity];
    }

    public Value get(Key key) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        int i = rank(key);
        if (i < N && keys[i].compareTo(key) == 0) {
            return vals[i];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void put(Key key, Value val) {
        int i = rank(key);
        // if the same key is found, update value
        if (i < N && keys[i].compareTo(key) == 0) {
            vals[i] = val;
            return;
        }
        // make room for new key,value pair to be inserted at position i
        for (int j = N; j > i; j--) {
            keys[j] = keys[j - 1];
            vals[j] = vals[j - 1];
        }
        // insert key and value
        keys[i] = key;
        vals[i] = val;
        N++;
    }

    public int rank(Key key) {
        int lo = 0, hi = N - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            int cmp = key.compareTo(keys[mid]);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else return mid;
        }
        return lo;
    }

    boolean contains(Key key) {
        return get(key) != null;
    }
    public int size() {
        return N;
    }
    boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SymbolTable<String, Integer> st = new SymbolTable<String, Integer>(2000);

        String word = "";

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) { 

            word = StdIn.readString(); // Read words/keys 
            if (!st.contains(word)) st.put(word, 1); 
            else st.put(word, st.get(word) + 1); 
        }

        st.function(3, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no method "contains" in your class. Have you tried to compile your code?

Comment: @mentallurg For the sake of minimalism, I did not show it here, because it is trivial. My whole program works perfectly fine, but the new function() I want to add is causing me problems, I don't see why the elements in vals[] are null

Comment: This would be great for a debugger.

Comment: @mentallurg I have added in the necessary functions now, including contains(), isEmpty() and size()

Comment: @0jnats3 take a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you posted above does not reproduce the problem – it doesn't compile for me locally.